# Trying to create a plugin to change wordpress site icons per page

Tags: plugins, favicon

I am trying to create a plugin to alter a WordPress websites default site icon set under appearance>customize.

I am unable to find and good resources/examples on how to modify the existing site icon urls for the 4 different sizes created by default.

I've read a lot on the different built in functions but can't put it together to get anything working. I currently have a case statement to check page id and then change the url ($favicon_link variable) to the site icon I want for certain pages that way but this doesn't account for the auto generated different sizes of icon wordpress normally creates.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

```
<?php
function wp_custom_icon_favicon_per_page ($meta_tags){  
    
    //$meta_tags = apply_filters( 'site_icon_meta_tags', $meta_tags );
    
    //Change base url depending on page ID
    switch(true){
    case is_page(9) :
      $favicon_link = 'http://localhost/testwp/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Logo2.png';
      break;
    case is_page(15) :
      $favicon_link = 'http://localhost/testwp/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Logo3.png';
      break;
    default : // Always need a fallback
      $favicon_link = 'http://localhost/testwp/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Logo1.png';
      break;
  }
    
    //Edit existing meta tags
    
    
}

//add_filter ( 'site_icon_meta_tags', 'wp_custom_icon_favicon_per_page');

add_action('wp_head', 'wp_custom_icon_favicon_per_page');

?>
```